# Excel macro doesn't work after sometime

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro in Excel which gets the data(html table) from a particular link , the macro works fine for 4-5 runs but it gets blank data after that . However if I record that macro again & run it works fine again for 4-5 runs. How can I resolve this ?

Adding the macro below (this is a recorded macro)

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;http" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$3")) 
        .Name = _
        "awadmin?commandname=appwatch&project=60115-VENOM&I=1&M=*&q=*&GO=Submit"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With // gets the data from the URL

```
Cells.Replace What:="Display System Objects", Replacement:="", LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Range("C8").Select
```

Comment: You need to explain better. 1. Post the code you've built. 2. What you're doing with it. 3. What you've tried so far. Edit your post to include this.

Comment: Recorderd macro's work with indications like ActiveSheet and Selected, that depend on wich Workbook, Sheet or Cell has the focus. If you click somewhere the macro might not work anymore or change its behaviour. Edit the macro after recording to avoid this and to be more specific in its actions.